# Android WorkManager setForegroundInfo

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I followed the official guide to set up a long-running worker with WorkManager (Kotlin version). Now I need to update the notification with the operation progress.
The documentation says:

// Calls setForegroundInfo() periodically when it needs to update
// the ongoing Notification

However I can't find any setForegroundInfo() method.
So how do you update the ongoing notification?

Comment: You may want to select an answer to help others.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running). A Kotlin app should call the `CoroutineWorker` method [setForeground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/CoroutineWorker#setforeground), a suspending function that makes the `CoroutineWorker` run in the context of a foreground service. Example:

```
setForeground(createForegroundInfo(myProgress))
```

The documentation contains another error: The [ForegroundInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ForegroundInfo) constructor has two arguments, not one. So the code:

```
return ForegroundInfo(notification)
```

should be

```
return ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notification)
```

where `notificationId` is an integer that uniquely identifies the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You could find detailed information in Google CodeLabs with examples.
There are 2 courses you can take:

1. [Background Work with WorkManager](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)
2. [Advanced WorkManager](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-adv-workmanager/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)

Comment: There is nothing in either codelabs about `ForegroundInfo`

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find any setForegroundInfo() method

Same to me, looks like the document is misleading the reader.

> So how do you update the ongoing notification?

Simply use the `NotificationManagerCompat.notify()` method, that's it.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of searching for `setForegroundInfo()`, you should use `setForegroundAsync()`

Comment: setForegroundAsync() is for Java, setForeground() for Kotlin.